# Querying one-to-many model in Google appengine

Tags: sql, google-app-engine

Suppose i've a one-to-many model that involves storing several books and their chapters like

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Chapter> chapters = new ArrayList<Chapter>();

    // getters and setters
}


@Entity
public class Chapter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    private String title;
    private int numPages;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Book book;

    // getters and setters
}
```

and then persisting it like

```
Book b = new Book();
b.setTitle("JDO 4eva");
Chapter c1 = new Chapter();
c1.setTitle("Intro");
c1.setNumPages(10);
b.getChapters().add(c1);
Chapter c2 = new Chapter();
c2.setTitle("Configuration");
c2.setNumPages(9);
b.getChapters().add(c2);

pm.currentTransaction().begin();
try {
    pm.makePersistent(b);
    pm.currentTransaction().commit();
} finally {
    if (pm.currentTransaction().isActive()) {
        pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

My question however is how do i select only chapters of a specific book only since all the chapters are stores in the same entity kind but there's not reference("foreign key") of the corresponding book.

In the normal sql i would for instance query it like "select * from chapters where book="book_id". What's the equivalent of this query in appengine? Thanks alot.

NB: I got some of the code from [here](http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2009/10/creating-bidrectional-owned-one-to-many.html) for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out myself.

Assuming the Key string of the book of the chapters i want to query is "agl2ZXJzZWZlZWRyDAsSBVRoZW1lGOQUDA", i use getObjectById() method of the persistence manager to get that book object and then a getter method to retrieve a list of chapters under it like;

```
Key BookKey = KeyFactory.stringToKey("agl2ZXJzZWZlZWRyDAsSBVRoZW1lGOQUDA");
Book book = pm.getObjectById(Book.class,BookKey);           

List<Chapter> chapters = book.getChapters();

for (Chapter chapter : chapters) {

  //work on your chapters
}
```

Hope this helps someone.